# What is the fastest way to shallow copy a (`__slots__`) object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

‘Fastest’ as in we’re trying to squeeze out every nanosecond. If the number of attributes is relevant, then let’s say it has one attribute.

Assume we want to shallow copy `c`:

```py
class C:
    __slots__ = (‘foo’,)
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

c = C()
```

`copy.copy` is impressively slow, so let’s say the baseline is `x = C(c.foo)`.

A slightly faster way to do this (by 7% on my machine) where `__new__` is irrelevant is:

```py
x = object.__new__(C, None)
x.foo = c.foo
```

I was trying to find a method copying raw bytes or something similar, but can’t seem to find anything.

Comment: It might be useful to include the method you are using to measure speed in the question.

Comment: If nanoseconds matter, then presumably you have many of these? Why do you use a class instead of let's say a list of just the `foo` values?

Comment: Also, nanoseconds almost certainly do *not* matter, aside from your desire to see a smaller number when you time this.